# How to fix bootloop after flashing GSIs with no recovery mode and fastboot available

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, boot-loop

I need help guys.
I am new to flashing and usage of ADB and fastboot. I have a Tecno pouvoir 3 plus and i decided to flash a GSI because the phone comes with android 9 and the manufacturers didn't release a new update ever since. After successful unlocking the bootloader through the official steps, i enter fastboot mode and flashed the official android 14 GSI since GSI's mainly work for all project treble compatible devices and i followed the steps cautiously and precisely, it worked with no errors, but i think because the GSI wasn't stable and fully compatible with my device, my phone entered a bootloop.
Then i was worried because i was new to this and then i entered into recovery mode, but instead of me to just try flashing a different GSI or my device firmware, i ignorantly tried flashing TWRP recovery through a tutorial, which i didn't do correctly and then i fell victim of A/B partition scheme, and now my phone is still in a bootloop but recovery mode isn't working anymore after i booted into TWRP's recovery.img when my device was currently in a bootlooped state, and now i don't know what to do because i can't enter recovery mode or fastboot inorder to fix the mistakes i made.
I was thinking of entering download/Odin mode inorder to flash my decive firmware back, but I don't know how to really do that. Can anyone help.

Comment: Just FYI: download/Odin mode is a special mode on Samsung devices, it's not available on other devices.

Comment: Your phone seem to use a Mediatek MT6739WA SoC. MediaTek has it's own proprietary Windows based flash tools which do not use bootloader or download mode. The last MediaTek device I had could be flashed only when it had been switched off. If this is still the same with your phone then this would be a possible way.

Comment: Thanks, I already did research and I found that there's a Tecno flash tool, which I used in successfully flashing my device firmware back. I'm currently using the phone in replying to this comment, thanks for all the help to all you guys. If it wasn't for the developing community, I wouldn't have fixed it .